# Nexus 7 (2013) WiFi Connection/Reconnection Issue

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-7

I have been using Nexus 7 (2013, Android 4.4.2) for a few months now, and it has issues with both work WiFi and home WiFi that all the other mobiles devices do not have (8 laptops plus a dozen Android & iOS phones/tablets).

Basically the issue is that *sometime* when I turn off WiFi and turn it back on, it either cannot find any WiFi AP or more often that it would only find some WiFi AP, and if I try to connect to a WiFi AP that I know is there and working, the connection would fail. The problem would either resolve itself within a few minutes (usually) or that I would be forced to reboot the device (rare).

So my question is that:

1. Is there anything I can do to fix it
2. Would sending it back to Asus help

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's related to "Wi-Fi optimization" option under "Advanced" setting in Wi-Fi screen. By turning it off I can consistently find the WiFi AP I was looking for. Once it's connected I can turn it on again without negative consequences.

**Edit:**
Nevermind, looks like it only help some of the time, there are still times when the device cannot find the AP every other device has no problem discovering and connecting to...

Answer (score -1):

You should consider updating your operating system, as bugs like this are usually fixed in newer versions.

Comment: It appears to have fixed itself with 5.0/5.1, but the hw is failing - all sensors would fail some time after rebooting, disabling auto orientation in the process, and the touch input may become unresponsive. Basically I found out the reason for its low, low price :-/